# WordPress Nonce not verifying

Tags: php, wordpress, nonce

I have a two step process when loggin in a user with a client app to the WordPress site

1st Step : Client app calls the API url of the WordPress site, it creates a nonce and returns the nonce token to the app.

```
$nonce = wp_create_nonce("my-action");
```

2nd Step : Client app loads the WordPress site using a Web view with a GET request including  the nonce in a GET parameter. Then verifies the nonce.

```
 wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['token'], 'my-action' );
```

I simulated this, with Postman and desktop browser. But nonce cannot be verified. It always fails.

This is where I create nonce

```
if(username_exists($username)){
            $user = get_user_by('login', $username );

            $result['status'] = "already_registered";

            $token = sha1(date('H:i'));
            $result['token'] = $token;

            $result['nonce'] = wp_create_nonce("my-action");

            return $result;

        }
```

This is where I check nonce...

```
function userAuth(){

    echo $_GET['token'];

    $nonce = wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['token'], 'my-action' );

    //Do more things based on above verification

}
```

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: post the code where you actually render the nonce (the <input> field and <form>).

Comment: Where are you printing your nonce? Where is your input form?

Comment: No input form. I use GET variable to pass it like this... `http://apidemo/?token=03b7c4cab0&username=333`

Comment: Well, could have put that in your question, and how you constructed your query string. But, if you are passing `nonce`, why do you verify `token`???

Comment: Yes I did mentioned I put nonce in a GET parameter. Actually, token is "nonce". I just renamed it for your ease.

Comment: My guess is, that these two happens in two clients now. Postman and Chrome. That's why nonce is failing. Can that be posiible ?

Comment: Doesn't matter if its GET or POST. We still need to see where do you construct that query, be it a form or an actual query string. Is not my "ease", if the code you post is wrong is not possible to guess what's going on. I see in your code that you are trying to verify the "token" parameter, but now you tell me you are actually sending the "nonce" parameter. So if the code is right, you are verifying the **WRONG PARAMETER**.

Comment: Post how you build the actual query string. Otherwise it is impossible to guess whats going on. If your previous comment is right, you simply sending one parameter and verifying another...

Answer (score 1):

I had the situation when `wp_verify_nonce()` on my live server WP site never returned true. And at the same time the site's copy (identical code) on my stage server validated this to true all the time.

Issue was the same page with the form comprising the nonce was **opened twice**  (in different Chrome windows) from the same live site URL. The second copy of the page was opened much later then the first (say 15 mins later). And I forgot about the first one being opened (that had generated the different nonce as being tied to the earlier time), trying to get the younger page form nonce verified with no success.

The reason was `wp_verify_nonce()` compared the younger page nonce with the older one somehow.

I.e. `wp_create_nonce()`, I repeated on my backend to test the issue, gave me two non-identical nonces. The one in the hidden form field that I sent via AJAX and the different one in my server AJAX handler next to the `wp_verify_nonce()` check line. The multiple `Ctrl-F5` + opened Chrome Dev Tools network with cache disabled had no effect. Nonces were different.

As soon as I closed the older page and cleared the cache for the new page the nonce verified to true.